# How to shorten names of query methods in Spring Data JPA Repositories?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Consider a Spring Data Jpa Repository:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndActivationKey(String activationKey);

    List<User> findAllByDeletedIsFalseAndActivatedIsFalseAndCreatedDateBefore(DateTime dateTime);

    User findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndLogin(String login);

    User findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail(String email);

}
```

Notice each method has "`DeletedIsFalse`" in it. Is there a simple way to make method names shorter? Like i.e.:

```
@FullMethodName("findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail")
User findOneByEmail(String email);
```

Comment: Is there a better solution for this problem in the current SDR version?

Answer (score 60):

Use `default` Java 8 feature for wrapping, just like so:

```java
interface UserInterface extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // use findOneByEmail instead
    User findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail(String email);
    
    default User findOneByEmail(String email) {
        return findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail(email);
    }
}
```

See [an example](https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-examples/blob/master/shadov/src/main/java/daggerok/ShadovApplication.java).

With Kotlin, you can use extension functions, for example:

```kotlin
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // use findOneByEmail instead
    fun findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail(email: String): User
}

fun UserRepository.findOneByEmail(email: String) =
    findOneByDeletedIsFalseAndEmail(email)
```

Comment: Should I enable something for that to work? Doesn't even find it in `search` for me.

Comment: @Shadov, what do you mean by enable? all you need is java 8, which is includes default keyword feature functionality: `default returnType shortMethodName(args) { return longMethoName(args); }`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work for me for some reason, no idea why, it's like my default methods are not there. Thought maybe I need to enable something.

Comment: checkout this: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-examples/blob/master/shadov/src/main/java/daggerok/ShadovApplication.java you can clone project and run locally to verify if it's working for you (see README: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-examples/blob/master/shadov/README.adoc)

Comment: If we want a better solution, I suggest voting this ticket up or making a better feature request 

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1213

Comment: I'm using this solution at the moment, but isn't each interface limited to one default method? What when another shortened name will be required?

Comment: @Funder, you can add number of default methods as many as you want

Comment: @Marksim that's right, I've noticed it in these days. There's stil some stuff to study for me :-D

Answer (score 13):

Now you can use Java 8 `default` interface [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) as @Maksim Kostromin described. But there is no such a feature in Spring.

-- Old answer

There is no such a way. You can specify any name for a method and add an annotation `@Query` with parameter value which holds desired query to database like this:

```java
@Query(value="select u from User u where u.deleted=false and u.email=:email")
User findOneByEmail(@Param("email")String email);
```

or, with native sql query:

```java
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted=false AND email=?1", nativeQuery=true)
User findOneByEmail(String email);
```

You can also use names that follow the naming convention for queries since `@Query` annotation will take precedence over query from method name.

[@Query docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Upd:

from Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_declared_queries):

> Although getting a query derived from the method name is quite convenient, one might face the situation in which ... the method name would get unnecessarily ugly. So you can either use JPA named queries through a naming convention ... or rather annotate your query method with @Query.