# formulate spring boot request

Tags: java, spring-data

when this request executed

```
   public List<Operation> findAllByOpeContratStartingWithAndOpeServeurStartingWithAndOpeDateStartingWithOrOpeDateStartingWith(String OpeContrat,String opeServeur,String opeDate1,String opeDate2);
```

just this findAllByOpeDateStartingWithOrOpeDateStartingWith is executed

Comment: At this point, it seems that the sheer bulk of the query name is counterproductive and you'd be better off using something more descriptive with `@Query` (and ideally a strongly-typed `LocalDate` instead of strings).

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019408/how-to-shorten-names-of-query-methods-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories

Comment: Have you validated your claim in a unit test?

Comment: It may help troubleshooting to see the generated queries. You can add this to your `application.properties`: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

Comment: I agree with @chrylis about using `@Query`. You may want to give a look at [QueryDsl and custom bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647967/5873923)